# UIView Not Appearing On UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have code to present a UIView over the status bar of the currentViewController. This code works on the first ViewController flawlessly, but when this code is ran from another viewController, the status bar goes away, but the label never animates nor does it show up?

The second VC is embedded in a NavigationController. That's the only difference.

I can't figure out why this isn't working, has anyone ran into this?

```
+ (UIView *) initializeSuccessfulSparkViewOnView: (UIView *) view
{
// Get View Width
CGRect viewRect = view.window.frame;
CGFloat viewWidth = viewRect.size.width;

// Custom popup for new users
UIView *successfulSparkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 20)];
[successfulSparkView setCenter: CGPointMake(viewWidth/2, -10)];
[successfulSparkView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithHexString: @"FF4300"]];

// Border
[[successfulSparkView layer] setBorderWidth: .30f];
[[successfulSparkView layer] setBorderColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

// Drop shadow
[[successfulSparkView layer] setShadowRadius: 1.0];
[[successfulSparkView layer] setShadowOpacity: 1.0];
[[successfulSparkView layer] setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(.1, .1)];
[[successfulSparkView layer] setShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[view addSubview: successfulSparkView];

// Label For Successful Spark Sent
UILabel *sparkSentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 20)];
[sparkSentLabel setCenter: CGPointMake([[successfulSparkView window] frame].size.width/2, 10)];

// If Device Model is 4 or 5, Make Smaller Text To Fit Screen
if ([[UIDevice model] containsString: @"iPhone 4"] || [[UIDevice model] containsString: @"iPhone 5"])
{
    [sparkSentLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue" size: 9]];
}
else
{
    [sparkSentLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue" size: 10]];
}

// Setup Label On UIView
[sparkSentLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[sparkSentLabel setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
[sparkSentLabel setText: @"Your Spark was sent successfully, and will be delivered at the selected time."];
[successfulSparkView addSubview: sparkSentLabel];
[successfulSparkView bringSubviewToFront: sparkSentLabel];

return successfulSparkView;
}

+ (void) presentSuccessfulSparkSentView
{
//GET CURRENT VIEWCONTROLLER
UIViewController *currentViewController = [UIViewController currentViewController];
UIView *successfulSparkView = [UIViewController initializeSuccessfulSparkViewOnView: [currentViewController view]];

CGRect viewRect = successfulSparkView.window.frame;
CGFloat viewWidth = viewRect.size.width;

//SHOW SUCCESSFUL VIEWCONTROLLER
float displayTime = .50;
[UIView animateWithDuration: displayTime delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [successfulSparkView setCenter: CGPointMake(viewWidth/2, 10)];
    [[[currentViewController view] window] setWindowLevel: UIWindowLevelStatusBar];
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
 }];

//DISMISS SUCCESSFUL VIEWCONTROLLER
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)((displayTime * 4) * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: displayTime delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:
     ^{
         [successfulSparkView setCenter: CGPointMake(viewWidth/2, -10)];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [[[currentViewController view] window] setWindowLevel: UIWindowLevelNormal];
     }];
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code like this

```
+ (void) presentSuccessfulSparkSentView
{
//GET CURRENT VIEWCONTROLLER
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [UIViewController currentViewController];
    if(currentViewController.navigationController != nil)
    {
        currentViewController = currentViewController.navigationController;
    }

......
```

I think that [UIViewController currentViewController] gets only UIViewController and you try to add UIView on it's view.

But, UINavigationBar is above the UIViewController, so If you add UIView on UIViewController's view, UINavigationBar hides it.

The best approach is add UIView on 'UIWindow'.

then you don't need to call [UIViewController currentViewController] and you don't need to care about UINavigationViewController and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Check your implementation on [UIViewController currentViewController]. You need to have to check if the controller you are fetching is a view controller or a navigation controller. If it is the latter, then you have to get the root view of that navigation to be returned as the currentViewController.